# NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available exception occurring intermittently: what is the exact cause?

Tags: elasticsearch

Need to finalize the exact root cause of "None of the configured nodes are available exception" occuring in elasticsearch.

The following are the list of possible causes found by searching available articles:
1.  Incorrect host/port/cluster name
2.  Incorrect version of log4j in application
3.  Mismatching version of elasticsearch JAR and Java/Transport client used
4.  GC taking more cycles and subsequently killing TCP connections
5.  Failure/disconnected/down Load balancer node
6. client.close() method is invoked before performing any operation Index/Search on client
7. Setting `client.transport.sniff=true`

```
sniffOnConnectionFault=true
```

property to true shall avoid this
8.  TCP connection settings in elasticsearch

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=600 
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60 
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=3
```

Configuration Details:
Elasticsearch version - 1.5.1
Client referred from elasticsearch-1.5.1.jar

elasticsearch.yml properties(externalized to properties file in web application)

```
elasticsearch.cluster.sniff=true
elasticsearch.cluster.enabled=true
elasticsearch.transport.timeout=60000
elasticsearch.search.timeout=60000

elasticsearch.status.yellow.timeout=10000
elasticsearch.index.ack.timeout=60000
elasticsearch.index.attachment.ack.timeout=45000
```

I have been verifying all the findings above on my application. But I need to pinpoint a specific condition or point as the exact root cause of this issue? Suggestions or Ideas to finalize on exact root cause.

Comment: Please specify elasticsearch and your client versions. Also - `elasticsearch.tml` content would help.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas edited post with version details. Thank you

Comment: Are you running it locally? If not, perhaps you forgot to turn off (open ports)   in firewall options?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas application is running in production. splunk log shows this exception multiple times within a duration of 10 seconds.  Around 30 instances of this exception in past 6 months. Subsequent requests after this exception (after a duration of 10 to 15 seconds) is processing successfully. Heap size looks normal. client.transport.sniff is enabled to true. Log4j version is verified and it is matching with 1.5.1 version of ES. No load balancer being used.